# plotting fill_between() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I created a pandas plot from two dataframes:

```
ttload.plot(legend=True, figsize=(12,7))
zzload.plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

Now, I would like to use the `fill_between` function to generate a shaded region between **0** (the orange line) and the **min and max values** of the blue line.

I have saved the min and max values of blue in variables `w_min` and `w_max`.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 12):

```
ax = ttload.plot(legend=True, figsize=(12,7))
zzload.plot(legend=False,ax=ax)

ax.fill_between(ttload.index,ttload['value'], zzload['value'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the pyplot tutorial?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = 1.2*np.sin(4*np.pi*x)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)

ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y1)
ax1.set_ylabel('between y1 and 0')

plt.show()
```